# Could not be able to get correct result of nexmo sample code

Tags: php, vonage

I created account at Nexmo and have tried this sample from [here](https://docs.nexmo.com/messaging/sms-api#php)

```
<?php
$url = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?' . http_build_query(
    [
      'api_key' =>  'API_KEY',
      'api_secret' => 'API_SECRET',
      'to' => 'HERE REAL NUMBER',
      'from' => 'HERE REAL NUMBER',
      'text' => 'Hello from Nexmo'
    ]
);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
```

but this code does not echo anything, when I try

```
curl "https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?api_key=KEY&api_secret=SECRET&from=NEXMO&to=911234567890&text=Welcome+to+Nexmo"
```

I get response as

```
 {
        "message-count": "1",
        "messages": [{
            "to": "911234567890",
            "message-id": "070000000279DB5A",
            "status": "0",
            "remaining-balance": "1.96000000",
            "message-price": "0.02000000",
            "network": "41001"
        }]
    }
```

How to make php code work correctly?

Comment: show var_dump($url); after http_build_query

Comment: I couldn't get it what are you asking for? will you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but still I'd like to answer it.
You have to replace the API_KEY and API_SECRET values with the ones NEXMO provided for your account.